# Multi-threaded make

Tags: multithreading, makefile

I can multi-thread a make with `make -jN`

Can I dictate multi-threading *within* the Makefile so that just `make` from the command-line runs multiple threads. Here's my makefile:

```
BIN_OBJS = $(wildcard *.bin)
HEX_OBJS = $(subst .bin,.hex,$(BIN_OBJS))

all: $(HEX_OBJS)

$(HEX_OBJS): %.hex: %.bin
    python ../../tools/bin2h.py $< > $@
```

Comment: Just realized I could do `all: $(MAKE) -j8 make2` or something like this, but hopefully there's a better option

Comment: You can suppress parallel operation with `.NOTPARALLEL:` as a pseudo-target.  I'm not aware of a way to force parallelism other than the command line options (see [GNU `make` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel)).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, to be clear, make is not multi-threaded.  Using `-j` just tells make to run multiple commands at the same time (in the background, basically).

Second, no, it's not possible to enable multiple jobs from within the makefile.  You don't want to do that, in general, anyway because other systems will have different numbers of cores and whatever value you choose won't work well on those systems.

You don't have to write multiple makefiles, though, you can just use:

```
BIN_OBJS = $(wildcard *.bin)
HEX_OBJS = $(subst .bin,.hex,$(BIN_OBJS))

.PHONY: all multi
multi:
        $(MAKE) -j8 all

all: $(HEX_OBJS)

$(HEX_OBJS): %.hex: %.bin
        python ../../tools/bin2h.py $< > $@
```

Comment: It might be sensible to set `MAX_PARALLEL = 8` and use `-j${MAX_PARALLEL}` so you can override the parallelism on the command line when desired.

Comment: @MadScientist that's perfectly suitable. Thanks

Comment: isn't running multiple commands at the same time, the same as running multiple threads?

Comment: No.  Running multiple commands is multiprocessing.  The distinction is in resource access: each process has its own memory and other resources, kept separate by the kernel, and no process can access another process's resources (except through explicit sharing but that's a complex topic).  Multiple threads all run inside the SAME PROCESS so they all have access to the same resources (with only a few bits, "thread local storage", restricted to each thread).  Multiprocessing you get for free on most OSs.  Multithreading requires you write your program in a particular way to support it.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful using -j if the filesystem where the make is occurring is an nfs share. I have seen odd results and had it mentioned to me that nfs mounted directories operate differently (some sort of file lock issue?)

I ran my multi makes from a script and checked cpuinfo to find out how many processors the build box had (was running same script against multiple architectures/build machines)

```
CPUCOUNT=$(grep -c   "^processor" /proc/cpuinfo)

if [ ${CPUCOUNT} -lt 1 -o ${CPUCOUNT} -gt 4 ]
then
    echo "Unexpected value for number of cpus, ${CPUCOUNT}, exiting ..."
    exit 16
fi

echo "This machine has ${CPUCOUNT} cpus, will use make -j${CPUCOUNT} where possible"
```